# display first found output from find command

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a script that is looking for the `RELEASE-NOTES*` file for all Tomcat installs I have on a system. However, `find` is finding multiple instances of this file in various install paths. Is there a way to only display the first found instance of each unique file based on the path? I want to do an exhaustive search, so the paths in the code need to remain the same.

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -- "/opt" "/var"  "/usr"

    for _i in "$@"; do
        find_release=$(find $_i -maxdepth 5 -name RELEASE-NOTES* 2>/dev/null)
        for found in $find_release; do
            echo $found
        done
    done
```

Output:

```
/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs/RELEASE-NOTES.txt
/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/RELEASE-NOTES.txt
/opt/tomcat7/webapps/docs/RELEASE-NOTES.txt
/opt/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/RELEASE-NOTES.txt
/opt/tomcat7/RELEASE-NOTES
```

Desired Output:
Just find the first instance of `RELEASE-NOTES*` in each path and skip to the next.

```
/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs/RELEASE-NOTES.txt
/opt/tomcat7/webapps/docs/RELEASE-NOTES.txt
```

Comment: What's the definition of "each path"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`- quit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-_002dquit):

> -quit
>
> Exit immediately [...] ‘-quit’ simply makes find stop immediately. No child processes will be left running. [...]

Adapting your example:

```sh
for _i in "/opt" "/var" "/usr"; do
    find "$_i" -maxdepth 5 -name "RELEASE-NOTES*" -print -quit
done
```